# Export highlighting in html when using bookmark+ in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I use the extension [BookMark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) for Emacs in order to highlight permanently section of texts.
[image: Screenshot]

Is there anyway to mirror the highlighting when using normal html export ?
And for reveal.js export ?

I have been advised to add the txt file as well, it simplifies the help process : [TextFile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6pr02p6sjp2h96/Lectures_Conf_Videos_Docus_PRO.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to integrate this with the org-mode export, but you can probably do this to get an html file with highlighting.

```
(let* ((html-buffer (htmlize-buffer))
       (html (with-current-buffer html-buffer
               (buffer-string))))
  (with-temp-file "test.html"
    (insert html))
  (kill-buffer html-buffer))

(browse-url "test.html")
```